# Colocar duas Arrays dentro de um foreach

Tags: php, array, loop, foreach

Bom, no caso eu tenho duas arrays que são recebidas de inputs, baseados em locação de quartos de um hotel, no caso, cada quarto precisa exibir Numero de adultos e crianças, consegui a ajuda de alguém aqui no stack para incrementar o numero de quartos, porém precisava colocar abaixo dos adultos a array $children, no caso, crianças pra cada quarto, mas esta dando erro aqui, alguém sabe se é possível fazer?

```
$adultos = array(2, 3, 2);
$criancas = array(1, 1, 3);

$i = 1;
foreach($adults as $adultos):

    echo "<strong>Quarto".$i++."</strong><br>";
    echo "Adultos:".$adultos."<br>";
    //AQUI PRECISAVA EXIBIR AS CRIANÇAS
    echo "Crianças:".$criancas."<br>";
endforeach;
```

estou me batendo aqui pra fazer isso, se alguém puder dar uma luz...

Comment: Ambos os *arrays* terão **sempre** o mesmo número de elementos ou isso não é garantido?

Comment: Se não for, qual a relação entre adultos e crianças? Porque precisam estar juntos?

Comment: Eu particularmente não iteraria com `foreach` nesse caso. Parece que a estrutura de dados não foi feita imaginando esse tipo de iteração. Essa é uma estrutura de referência pelo índice, então você está muito provavelmente condenado a usar o índice (ou a converter em outra estrutura de dados, usando o índice como intermediário possivelmente)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os valores de `$adultos` e `$criancas` estiverem diretamente relacionados, ficará melhor você agrupar os valores. É possível fazer isso através da função `array_map`:

```
$adultos = array(2, 3, 2);
$criancas = array(1, 1, 3);

$quantidades = array_map(null, $adultos, $criancas);
```

Formando o seguinte *array*:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Para percorrê-lo, basta utilizar o `foreach` em conjunto com `list`:

```
foreach($quantidades as $i => $quantidade) {
    list($adulto, $crianca) = $quantidade;
    echo "Quarto: ", $i+1, PHP_EOL;
    echo "Adultos: ", $adulto, PHP_EOL;
    echo "Crianças: ", $crianca, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Gerando o resultado:

```
Quarto: 1
Adultos: 2
Crianças: 1

Quarto: 2
Adultos: 3
Crianças: 1

Quarto: 3
Adultos: 2
Crianças: 3
```

Que é o esperado.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/3N0ile).

Comment: na realidade eles vão ficar sempre diferentes, os valores, pois o usuário vai preencher em um form os dados, se tiver criança ou não, quantos adultos, e um input "infinito" pra cada quarto, esse input "infinito" que gera o array.

Comment: Tem como explicar melhor? Então esta solução não resolve o problema? Por quê?

Comment: ah sim, agora deu certo, eu não tinha declarado a variavel "$quantidade" mas deu certo agora, muito Obrigado de novo Anderson! Tenha uma ótima semana amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Está comentado o código para poder entender.

```
$adultos = array(2, 3, 2);
$criancas = array(1, 1, 3);

$i = 0; // Altere o valor da variável $i para 0
foreach($adultos as $adultos): // Corrija o nome da variável $adultos pois está $adults
    echo "<strong>Quarto ".($i+1)."</strong>\n"; // ($i+1) soma o valor de $i com mais 1, apenas para exibição.
    echo "Adultos:".$adultos."\n";
    //AQUI PRECISAVA EXIBIR AS CRIANÇAS
    // O valor da variável $i vai ser a chave para retornar a quantidade de crianças
    echo "Crianças:".$criancas[$i]."\n\n"; // Exibe a quantidade de crianças
    $i++; // Incrementa
endforeach;
```

Pode ver funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/UJElx4).